# Possible to create 'transaction' for adding new user via firebase auth and writing to firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a step in my new user flow where a user is registered with Firebase auth, and then a record is written to Firestore.

Is there a straightforward way to put both the user registration and the firebase write into a transaction, so if either one fails, they both fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a straightforward way to put both the user registration and the firebase write into a transaction, so if either one fails, they both fail?

There are no [Firebase products](https://firebase.google.com/products-build) that support cross-product transactional operations. You'll have to nest both calls and always handle the errors. So do the authentication, and then write the data to [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) or the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database).

A more convenient way of handling this situation would be to [trigger a Cloud Functions in response to the creation of a Firebase user account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events). In this way, you will only need to handle a single operation on the client.